# Flat Rate shipping method not showing in admin create order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Some shipping methods are not showing (including Flat rate shipping method) on order create page in admin.

Could you please help me anyone whats the issue?

Comment: Can u some piece of your code

Comment: there is no custom code... I am using Amasty ShippingPerItem extension